# Table like structure in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

can anybody guide me on how one can create excel like spreadsheet or simply a table in android where he can add the values under a column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [TableLayout view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html) or setup a custom ListView depending on your specifications.